# Column name DIV shows error in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am trying to execute the below code in hive:

`create table xyz (name string,div int) ;`

It shows error. Cant we use a column in hive with name `div` ? I have a large table that has a column `div`, executing that hql throwed me below error. That is how i tried with a smaller hql as the one above, and it shows same error. I am using hive 0.13.

`NoViableAltException(14@[])`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.identifier(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:11627)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.identifier(HiveParser.java:40134)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:34747)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:32979)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4544)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2144)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1398)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1036)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:408)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:322)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:976)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1041)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:912)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:902)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:793)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)`
 `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
 `at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)`
 `at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`
 `at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)`
 `at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)`
FAILED: ParseException line 2:15 cannot recognize input near 'div' 'int' ')' in column specification`

Comment: Div is a SQL reserved word , hence this keyword is blocked from usage in hive.Also your ` workaround works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer is found!

```
create table xyz (name string, `div` int);
```

This works! Surround div with "`" symbol and then it works.

I suppose div would be a keyword in hive (not found in any document though).

Thanks,
Neethu